# jQuery rcarousel - slide wait time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using [rcarousel](http://ryrych.github.io/rcarousel/) and would like to change the time that it stays on each slide. Right now it stays for a couple of seconds but I would like to increase this so the slide is displayed for at least 10 seconds.

Is this possible? Reading the documentation on jQuery rcarousel I couldn't see any setting that does this.

I've tried the following:

**HTML**

```html
<div id="carousel">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kCURPp5.png" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kCURPp5.png" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kCURPp5.png" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kCURPp5.png" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kCURPp5.png" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kCURPp5.png" />
</div>
```

With the following **JavaScript**

```js
$(function () {
    $("#carousel").rcarousel({
        speed: 5000
    });
});
```

But this changes the transition speed.  I want to change the length of time for pausing between images.

See this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/8bRLb/2/)

Comment: -1 because you clearly didn't read the documentation.

Comment: -1 because you don't read the docs

Comment: Thanks. I did read the response please see my edit.

Comment: What you're looking for is `auto: {enabled:true,interval:10000}`.  I'll post as an answer if the question is reopened.

Comment: Can we vote to re-open?  The question, as it currently stands, is a good format for this site and does not currently have an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `interval` property on the [`auto`](http://ryrych.github.io/rcarousel/#options) option.

Use the following JavaScript to set:

```js
$(function () {
    $("#carousel").rcarousel({
        auto: {
            enabled: true,
            interval: 1000}
    });
});
```

*note: currently set to 1 second for demo, but add another 0 if you'd like it to take 10 seconds*

## [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/8bRLb/)